# Rails 3.0: Adding new action to a controller

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3

Before rails 3.0, adding a new action to a controller was easy.

You merely add a new method `foobar` to the controller class (called mycontroller).
Add an html file in the views folder for that controller, `foobar.html.erb`

Then, if you point the browser to `.../mycontroller/foobar` everything worked.

However, in rails 3.0 when i added a new action as described above, i get the following error:

> No route matches "/mycontroller/foobar"

What changed in rails 3.0? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 19):

Add this to `routes.rb`:

```
get 'mycontroller/foobar'
```

This will route the URL `http://mysite.com/foobar` to the `foobar` action using HTTP GET.

Some more info:

1. Note that defining a `def foobar` in the controller is not a strict requirement (unless you need to do something in `foobar` before the view is displayed) - but the view must exist. In other words, even if `def foobar` method does not exist in the controller, the view `foobar.html.erb` will still be rendered.
2. Here is a [good overview of routes in Rails 3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).
3. Also, in case you don't already know, you can list all the routes that you app knows about using `rake routes`. Consequently, if the output of `rake routes` does not list the route to some controller/action, then the 'No route matches' error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all. You have no corresponding route in your config/routes.rb. Check if the default route is commented out. If so, you would need to add a route for your new action.